# I'm looking for a textbook based introduction to the php 5? Any suggestions?

Tags: php

By textbook based i mean the author asks the reader questions/mini projects after every section/chapter of the book.  And the book includes background info on php 5, like what kind of language, its use, syntax/semantix/structure etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sams "Teach Yourself PHP in 24 Hours" is a good starting point. It gradually increases your exposure to PHP and its features.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend "Learning PHP 5" by David Sklar (ISBN-13 978-0-596-00560-3)

This book will walk you through from the basic syntax to some more advanced topics (pace may be a little slow if you are already familiar with basic programming). This book has numerous exercises to help you test your knowledge.